# How to match the email addresss with social media profile?

Tags: email, social-media, networking

I am willing to attempt a methodology that will help me to correlate an email addresses to the social media profiles.
I have tried to find out way through which it will be comfortable and faster to match the email address and the profiles.
I found a chrome extension: https://www.manycontacts.com/
I have added it to my gmail profile and I have tried to modify or findout how this extension is working using my reverse process skills. But I could find out how it is possible.
I came across [Spokeo.com](http://spokeo.com) but still the same thing. I am not able to figure out how this is happening and how I can create an app that can perform the exact functionality for me.
Kindly, let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: There are no straight forward ways to achieve this, no social media platform exposes APIs to do what you're asking. They're all hacky ways

Comment: Sorry but the question is considered off-topic because it is more about browsers and social media rather than administrating your site. In addition to that the solution required would be tools ,resources or software which is also considers off-topic. Please visit our help centre for further advice.